# Source Code File Cannot resolve symbol 'R'

Tags: android

I recently saw AlertDialog, I want to look at his source code, follow up, found the AlertController file, and then in its AlertController .setupView() method,

```
final View parentPanel = mWindow.findViewById(R.id.parentPanel);
final View defaultTopPanel = parentPanel.findViewById(R.id.topPanel);
final View defaultContentPanel = parentPanel.findViewById(R.id.contentPanel);
final View defaultButtonPanel = parentPanel.findViewById(R.id.buttonPanel);
```

Prompt me Cannot resolve symbol 'R', if I want to see the corresponding xml file, or I can click in, what should I do?

AlertController .setupView()

```
final View parentPanel = mWindow.findViewById(R.id.parentPanel);
final View defaultTopPanel = parentPanel.findViewById(R.id.topPanel);
final View defaultContentPanel = parentPanel.findViewById(R.id.contentPanel);
final View defaultButtonPanel = parentPanel.findViewById(R.id.buttonPanel);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close the project. Delete .gradle , .idea folders of the project and then reopen the project. and then try a fresh re-build and then you're good to go.

Else try invalidate caches and restart.

Comment: I tried your method, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @dafa  Hey could you please try to delete the caches folder of the Android studio then and then re-build the project .